# pyodbc SQL Query to Numpy array typeerror: bytes-like object required

Tags: python, sql, arrays, numpy

I've been trying to pull data from SQL database using pyodbc and want to place it into numpy.array. However I found difficulty in inputting multiple data-type for np.fromiter() argument.

```
import pyodbc as od
import numpy as np

con = od.connect('DSN=dBASE; UID=user; PWD=pass')
cursor = con.cursor()
SQLCommand = (
    """
    SELECT 

      [Item No_]
      ,sum ([Quantity]) as TotQty
      ,sum ([Discount Amount]) as DiscAmount
      ,sum ([Cost Amount]) as CostAmount
      ,[Date]
      ,sum ([Net Amount]) as NetAmount
      ,sum ([VAT Amount]) as VATAmount  
      ,sum ([Refund Qty_]) as RefundQty


  FROM database
  where [DATE] between ('2015-12-01 00:00:00.000') and ('2015-12-31 00:00:00.000') and [area No_] = '123'
  group by ROLLUP([DATE],[Item No_]);

    """)

cursor.execute(SQLCommand)
results = cursor.fetchall()
results_as_list = [i[0] for i in results]
array = np.fromiter(results_as_list, dtype="str, float, float, datetime64,float,float,float")
print(array[:5,:])
```

And I get this error

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to pass one iterable, specifically the first column of query, with multiple dtypes. [Numpy.iter()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromiter.html) takes only one object and type. Consider passing each column of query resultset as a one-dimensional iterable. Also for string (variable-length) you need to specify length and for date include the suffix if `[D]` date only or with time `[s]`.

```
cursor.execute(SQLCommand)
results = cursor.fetchall()

array = [np.fromiter([i[0] for i in results], dtype="|S50"),
         np.fromiter([i[1] for i in results], dtype="float"),
         np.fromiter([i[2] for i in results], dtype="float"),
         np.fromiter([i[3] for i in results], dtype="float"),
         np.fromiter([i[4] for i in results], dtype="datetime64[s]"),
         np.fromiter([i[5] for i in results], dtype="float"),
         np.fromiter([i[6] for i in results], dtype="float"),
         np.fromiter([i[7] for i in results], dtype="float")]
```

Alternatively, created an array of matrices:

```
array = np.array([np.matrix([i[0] for i in results], dtype="str"),
                  np.matrix([i[1] for i in results], dtype="float"),
                  np.matrix([i[2] for i in results], dtype="float"),
                  np.matrix([i[3] for i in results], dtype="float"),
                  np.matrix([i[4] for i in results], dtype="str"),
                  np.matrix([i[5] for i in results], dtype="float"),
                  np.matrix([i[6] for i in results], dtype="float"),
                  np.matrix([i[7] for i in results], dtype="float")])
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! May I also know the meaning of "|S50" , I try to google it but didn't found any reference on that.

Comment: Great! That's setting the [character limit of string](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html) as it is a variable-length dtype by default. Here, 50 characters are used. Adjust as needed.